# mysql one to many return, dealing with pagination

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have the following (abbreviated) tables:

```
resource
id | name

resource_category
resource_id | category_id

category
id | name
```

When I want to get the resources and all the assigned categories I use
the following sql:

```sql
SELECT resource.id. resource.name, category.id, category.name FROM resource
LEFT JOIN resource_category ON resource_category.resource_id = resource.id
LEFT JOIN category ON category.id = resource_category.category_id
```

This will get the following resourlces

```
resource.name1 | 1 | category1
resource.name1 | 2 | category2
resource.name1 | 5 | category5
resource.name2 | 5 | category5
resource.name2 | 6 | category6
resource.name2 | 1 | category1
```

I was then looping through and compressing the results into arrays

```php
foreach( $results as $result ) {
    $resources[$result['id']]['resource'] = $result;
    $resources[$result['id']]['categories'][$result['category_id']] =
    $result['category_name'];
}
```

Then I'd have a resource and all of it's categories.

The problem I'm running into is that when I start doing pagination and
use LIMIT, the results are giving 10 results, but since there's
multiple results for a single resource, when I compress it I get 2
actual resources instead of 10. Any suggestions?

I was trying to stay away from the below code:

```php
foreach( $results as $result ) {
      $resources[$result['id']]['resource'] = $result;
      $resources[$result['id']]['categories'] =
      $this->resource_model->get_categories( $result['id'] );
}
```

Comment: What are you using for pagination? Instead of using the number of records returned by sql as your item count you would want to use the count on $resources, which would be 1 for each resource with the categories being associated meta data. In this case, 2 records each with n categories.

Comment: I'm using mysql LIMIT to do pagination, e.g. LIMIT 0, 10. The problem with that method is that I don't know how rows to get because each item could have a variable number of categories associated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is that you need a stable sort.  Explicitly add an `order by`:

```
SELECT resource.id. resource.name, category.id, category.name
FROM resource
LEFT JOIN resource_category ON resource_category.resource_id = resource.id
LEFT JOIN category ON category.id = resource_category.category_id
order by resource.id, category.id;
```

If you are just putting these in arrays, try `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT resource.id. resource.name,
       group_concat(category.id) as cids,
       group_concat(category.name) as cnames
FROM resource
LEFT JOIN resource_category ON resource_category.resource_id = resource.id
LEFT JOIN category ON category.id = resource_category.category_id
group by resource.id;
```

Comment: Hmmm if I do it with group_concat then I have to explode the strings later .... I'll think about this. I did have a order_by on my actual queries, so that's covered thanks.